# Ubuntu is vulnerable to viruses from the internet?

Tags: malware

Ubuntu can be affected by visiting websites that google has labeled attack site.?

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked before and referring to Oli's response yes they can be effected by some. If they are exploiting your browser you can be affected or they are `java applet` (since `java` is cross-platform and runs on `java machine`). However if they try to install a program or driver, (as most do) they cannot infect your system since those are mostly written for windwos machines.